# QT Creator editor not finding include files

Tags: qt-creator

I just upgraded from QTcreator 1.3.1 to 2.7.0. In each version I am "importing" an existing project by specifying a directory that QT Creator then scans for scons files. In the old version I used to be able to F2 between instances and definitions.

For example: if I F2 while highlighting MYSTRUCT in file1, it will automatically jump to file2.

file1.h:

```
#include <file2.h>
MYSTRUCT instance;
```

file2.h:

```
MYSTRUCT{}
```

However, this isn't working anymore in the new version. I haven't changed the code. I don't use QT Creator to build; I use scons from command line. Compiling works fine as always. Is there a setting I need to change?

I thought that the .files and .includes files for my project specified all the files that QT Creator "knows" about. Both these files show all of the correct headers and source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling the same issue some time ago. I even sent a question to qt-creator support list and received some answer, which unfortunately doesn't work for me. So I was forced to return back to version 2.6.2.

[A link to thread on qt-creator support lint](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-creator/2013-April/002045.html)

Comment: yeah, the answer suggested in your link didn't work. I had to downgrade back to 2.6.2 as well.